# Optimizing CTE in SQL

Tags: sql, database, optimization, query-optimization, common-table-expression

I have a stored procedure which uses CTE, currently it is given as inline query in C# code. now i i have created a SQL stored procedure, it takes more time to execute than the inline query. i need to optimize the code. Please help me on this. Thanks in advance.

I am using **SQL SERVER DB**

This is the Stored procedure which i have created.

```
BEGIN

WITH MyCTE AS ( 
  SELECT i.Id, ParentId, i.Name, i.Description, 
  i.Name as ParentName, 
  i.Description as ParentDescription,
  1 as level, i.Id as ItemKey 
  FROM tableA i
  JOIN tableB l ON l.Id=i.ListId
  WHERE l.Name=@listName 
  and i.Lifecyclestatus in ('A','D')
  UNION ALL
  SELECT i.Id, i.ParentId, x.Name Name, x.Description, 
  i.Name ParentName, 
  i.Description as ParentDescription,
  x.Level+1, X.ItemKey 
  FROM tableA i
  JOIN MyCTE x ON i.Id = x.ParentId
)

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT r.ItemKey as ItemKey, r.Name as Name,
  r.Description, 
  STRING_AGG(r.ParentName, '$$')
  WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY r.Level DESC) as Path
  FROM MyCTE r
  GROUP By r.ItemKey, r.Name, r.Description ) H
WHERE H.Path LIKE '%' + @searchExpression + '%' 
OR H.Description LIKE '%' + @searchExpression + '%';

end
```

Please help me on this, i need to optimize this code

Comment: Please tag your question with the DBMS you are using. Also, update your question with the output of EXPLAIN PLAN for this query

Comment: Are you using oracle DBMS?

Comment: Each make and version of database server has its own dialect of SQL. Please [edit] your question to add a [tag](//stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database you use. [tag:postgresql]? [tag:mysql]? [tag:sql-server]? [tag:oracle]? [tag:google-bigquery]? [tag:amazon-redshift]? Another?

Comment: **Can anyone help me on this please** i need to complete this task by today

Comment: Possibly - but only if you provide the information I previously asked for